# How can I copy array from a Matlab struct array with fields to a struct of arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct

I currently have a struct of arrays:

```
t2 = 

cotrain_idx: [7x1 double]
 trvate_idx: [7x1 double]
 conf_param: 0
  is_target: 0
   orig_idx: 0
```

I also have an struct array with fields:

```
t3 = 

1x7 struct array with fields:

    type
    latency
    urevent
    ImageName
    isTarget
    isAccurate
    origEventIdx
```

I would like to copy all the elements comprising t3.isTarget to t2.is_target. However all my attempts result in errors:

```
t2.is_target(:)=t3(:).isTarget;
```

seems to onlt copy the first element, even though t3(:).isTarget clearly returns all 7 elements:

```
>>> t3(:).isTarget

ans =

     0


ans =

     1


ans =

     1


ans =

     1


ans =

     1


ans =

     1


ans =

     1
```

Is there something obvious that I'm missing here? If I have to, I can copy the elements in one at a time, but I expect Matlab has a more efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following, with a simplified version of you strcture:

```
t2.a1=123

t3(1).isTarget=1
t3(2).isTarget=2
t3(3).isTarget=3

t2.isTarget=[t3.isTarget]
```

You ca access to all the element of the `t3.isTarget` field by using `[]`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks. Is there an intuitive way to understand why this is the correct answer?

Comment: The `[]` work as `array concatenation operator`. They get the single values returned by the instruction `t3.isTarget` (which lists the element of the field `isTarget` of each element of the `t3` array) and build the array `isTarget` in the `t2` struct.